# ListView with condition in the data Django

Tags: django, listview, django-models, django-views, conditional-statements

i'm new on Django, and I would like to know how can I create a kind of filter so that only an object appears if it meets a condition in one of its attributes. I tried to do it with tags in the template but it did not work and I don't know if it is the most efficient way. The case is for example that I would like to see in my table the objects that in their attribute "asignar" have a specific value for example the text "Pedro". I'm open to suggestions that do not necessarily apply with labels.

Models.py:

```
class reporte_fallo(models.Model):
    num_inventario = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    serie = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    falla = models.TextField()
    descripcion = models.TextField()

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    area = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=LOAN_STATUS,blank=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    asignar = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=True)
    fecha_comp = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

View.py:

```
class reportelist(ListView):
    model = reporte_fallo
    template_name = 'formulario/reporte_list_jefe.html'
```

Template.html (This is my template that did not work using tags in this case the part "and report.assign == "Pedro" on the if, it just send the message "The list is empty")

```
    <tbody>
    {% if object_list and reporte.asignar == "Pedro" %} 
    {% for reporte in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{reporte.id}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{reporte.falla}}</td>
        <td>{{reporte.fecha}}</td>
        <td>{{reporte.area}}</td>
        <td>{{reporte.asignar}}</td>
        <td>{{reporte.fecha_comp}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <a href="{% url 'formulario:reporte_editar' reporte.id %}">Asignar</a>
        <a href="{% url 'formulario:reporte_eliminar' reporte.id %}">Eliminar</a>       
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <h1>The list is empty</h1>
    {% endif%}
</tbody>
```

I hope your answer thnks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template the `if` conditional should be moved inside the `{% for %}` loop. Something along the lines of:

```html
{% for reporte in object_list %}
{% if reporte.asignar == "Pedro" %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{reporte.id}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want to see `reporte.asignar == "Pedro"` objects it might be worth overriding the [queryset in the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
# views.py
class reportelist(ListView):
    model = reporte_fallo
    template_name = 'formulario/reporte_list_jefe.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(asignar='Pedro')
```

Then there's no need to check in the template:

```html
{% for reporte in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{reporte.id}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! You are huge, my problem was that i didn't know what could I do by overwriting a view, but thank you.